# Intelij Idea Android Application Development Compile Time Check

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, ide

I am very new to Android/Java Development.
I have an application that should run on API Level 10 and above.

this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"
  android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

and this is my application structure in InteliJ Idea IDE.

[image]

According to android documents **PopupMenu** added in API Level 11 but when I use **PopupMenu** in any activity, application compile successfully! i think IDE should inform me in some way like compile time error or warning.

I configured application or IDE incorrectly? or I should check every component that used in application manually, to ensure about minimum SDK compatibility?

thanks.

**UPDATE**

This is snapshot of my code, there is no warning in code editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ does show a warning to indicate that you are using Classes which are not supported by your minimum SDK level, in your case at the lines of code where you use the PopupMenu, but it will still compile. When you try to run the application on a API Level 10 device it will crash as soon as you use the PopupMenu inside your App.

**EDIT:**

Maybe you Module SDK is not set correctly, try this:

1) Go to Modules in Project Structre
2) Select your Android App Module
3) In the Dependencies Tab select the correct SDK for your App.

In your case you should select "Android 2.3.3 Google API's" which corresponds to API level 10.

Comment: thanks, I have updated my question and add snapshot of my code editor. there is no warning.

Comment: Done! But now its compiling with API Version 10 and not compile at all.